# Why can't I place desktop icons everywhere when snapped to grid?

Tags: macos, desktop

The area marked in the image cannot be used for desktop icons.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to drop an icon there?

Comment: It just snaps back to its previous position

Answer (score 1):

The filename is probably too long on the folder next to where you're trying to place it.
Try moving those Untitled folders over one grid space & test using the short name folders at the top.

Comment: I deleted all the untitled folders and tried single-letter folder names, this does't work either.

Comment: What happens if you try it just using the documents, rather than folders? I still think it's a sizing issue. Next try dropping your icon size a bit, they're like dinner plates ;-) ... or increasing your spacing. Also... grab all the icons & move them half an inch, make sure they are all snapped to the current grid.

Comment: Just tried multiple settings, including [min icon size, max grid spacing], [max icon size, min spacing], and [min icon size, min spacing]. It seems every possible setting doesn't allow files/folders/aliases to be snapped to the left and bottom edges of the desktop. The only way to get them to the left and bottom edges is to place them close, and then resize the grid to make them appear there.

Comment: Aha, I played around a bit more and I somehow found a sweet spot, it looks tidy now!